# My toilet bowl drains when my neighbor flushes his toilet

Tags: toilet, drains

About three months ago, my neighbor renovated his bathroom.  We have a common wall between the master bathrooms in the condo.  When he flushes his toilet, my toilet bowl drains.  He installed a new efficient toilet.  The building was built in 1993.  No idea as to why this is happening. Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a problem with the venting.  Your neighbor's toilet is likely not vented properly, so when they flush it siphons your toilet.

Contact a local plumber, and/or the building manager, and have the problem investigated.

Comment: I'm guessing neither side is properly vented, could be one vent for both units and it has clogged.